React Error when trying to filter data after retreival
When I attempt to format the data being received from TableData I keep getting an error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace'). This happens when I reload the page after trying to filter the data I have put a comment in the code to show the line that when i refresh and add the code it gives me the error.
function ShiftViewTable({ tableData }) {
  const checkMobile = useCheckMobileScreen();
  console.log(checkMobile);

  const handleDetailsView = (props) => {
    return (
      <Link className="details-link" to={`/${props.data._id}`}>
        {Moment(props.value).format("MMMM-DD-YYYY")}
      </Link>
    );
  };

  const [colDefs, setColDefs] = useState([
    { field: "date", cellRenderer: handleDetailsView },
    { field: "log_name" },
    {
      field: "critical_updates",
      flex: 2,
      valueFormatter: (text) => text.value.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ""), **//when i refresh the page with this it says the error**
    },
    { field: "ticket_updates", flex: 2 },
  ]);

Anyway I try to filter data after retrieving from backend I get this type of error.

You are getting error as text.value is not defined inside useState block when useState is running to create the default value of colDefs.
If colDefs is supposed to be a definition for some 3rd party table component i would suggest keeping it as general variable and not as a state.
As a fellow newbie to stack overflow there are some suggestions i would like to make here.
Share a sandbox with your issue reproducible if you can or at least min reproducible code if possible, if not at least provide all details of 3rd party packages you are using and any relevant info.
Looking at your shared code, I have no idea what valueFormatter is or why you are using something that looks like a formatting option to create table column definition inside a useState default value assignment.
This is not a definite answer, posting this as i can't add comments yet. Feel free to delete if not helpful and accept if helpful.
